# Trying to make a ChatBot, but for some reason it isnt responding to messages, code and another problem is provided below

Tags: discord, discord.py

Oh and another problem it has is that it doesnt print the user_message in console as it should in line 12

```
client = discord.Client(command_prefix='',intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel.name)
        print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

        if user_message == 'Hello':
              await message.channel.send('Howdy!')
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is all messed up here; starting with your second `client.event`, your code is indented way too far; here's how the code should look:

```
client = discord.Client(command_prefix='',intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

# Indentation fixed here

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if user_message == 'Hello':
          await message.channel.send('Howdy!')
```

Comment: ok thanks, my shitty indentation was a problem indeed, but it still didnt work after i fixed it, but nvm that, i managed to do it another way, thanks for helping!